# System.OutofMemoryException - Parser para arquivos grandes

Tags: c#, memória, memory-limit

Criei uma gramática simples para interpretar um arquivo cujo o formato é bem parecido com um JSON. Porém, quando tento fazer um parse do arquivo recebo a exceção `Sytem.OutOfMemoryException`. Isso ocorre, por causa do tamanho do arquivo que estou tentando fazer o parse. O arquivo tem 108MB e 4.682.073 de linhas.

Quanto faço o parse de arquivos menores, tudo funciona normalmente, porém, para esse arquivo, percebo que quando a memória ocupada pelo processo chega a quase 2GB a exceção é disparada e o programa para. A exceção vem do código gerado para o parser com a extensão do ANTLR para Visual Studio.

Como eu faço para executar o *parser* para um arquivos realmente grandes com ANTLR?

#### Mais informações

A máquina que estou executando o parser tem 8GB de memória, processador de 2.8 GHz (intel core 2 duo).

Exemplo do problema

#### Arquivo de exemplo para leitura

```
(
    :field ("ObjectName"
        :field (
            :field ("{6BF621F9-A0E2-49BB-A86B-3DE4750954F4}")
            :field (Value)
            :field (Value)
            :field (
                :Time ("Sun Jan 26 10:08:33 2014")
                :last_modified_utc (1390730913)
                :By ("Mensagem qualquer")
                :From (localhost)
            )
            :field ("Applications/application_fw1")
            :field (false)
            :field (false)
        )
        :field ()
        :field ()
        :field ()
        :field (0)
        :field (true)
        :field (true)
    )
.
.
.
Milhares de outros fields.
.
.
.
)
```

#### A gramática

```
grammar Objects;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */


compileUnit
    : obj
    ;


obj
    : OPEN ID? (field)* CLOSE
    ;

field
    : ':'(ID)? obj
    ;


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */


OPEN 
    : '(' 
    ;

CLOSE 
    : ')' 
    ;

ID
    : (ALPHA | ALPHA_IN_STRING)
    ;


fragment
INT_ID
    : ('0'..'9')
    ;

fragment
ALPHA_EACH
    : 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | INT_ID | '-' | '.' | '@'
    ;

fragment
ALPHA
    : (ALPHA_EACH)+
    ;

fragment
ALPHA_IN_STRING
    : ('"' ( ~[\r\n] )+ '"')
    ;



WS
    // :    ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip  // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
    ;
```

#### Execução do *parser*

```
// text é o texto do arquivo de 108MB que será lido.
var input = new Antlr4.Runtime.AntlrInputStream(text);
var lexer = new ObjectsLexer(input);
var tokens = new Antlr4.Runtime.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new ObjectsParser(tokens);

// Contexto para a regra compileUnit
// ERRO: Aqui ocorre o problema. Quando inicia a montagem da árvore para compileUnit
// Não chega no Visitor, a exceção ocorre em compileUnit()
var ctx = parser.compileUnit();


// Execução do visitor
new ObjectsVisitor().Visit(ctx);
```

Comment: Você pode por favor colocar um exemplo do código que está usando para o parse?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez adicionado um exemplo

Answer (score 2):

É possível definir algumas coisas para evitar o problema:

- [Evitando a construção de uma árvore gigante no `parser`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#setBuildParseTree%28boolean%29);
- [Usando `UnbufferedTokenStream` no `parser`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/UnbufferedTokenStream.html);
- [Usando `UnbufferedCharStream` no `lexer`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/UnbufferedCharStream.html);

Ao compilar a unidade de trabalho, o *framework* tenta carregar o arquivo e a árvore inteira em memória. Em teoria, o espaço de endereçamento da aplicação é 4Gb, mas creio que a limitação de 2Gb seja pelo tamanho máximo da estrutura de dados dentro do processo.

Eliminando a necessidade do buffer, o arquivo é carregado de forma segmentada, assim como a árvore de `parse`, e o problema de memória é evitado.

Comment: A exceção parou de ocorrer após colocar o `parser.BuildParseTree = false;`, o resto não foi necessário. Mas isso faz com que o meu visitor não consiga navegar na árvore (por não existe árvore?!). Tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Procurei alguma coisa, mas aí já fica específico demais. Não conheço o ANTLR tão a fundo assim.